# 2 Group by with UNION in PHP MYSql

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, sum

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(pl.id) as count,addby,SUM(pl.wghvalue) as wghval
FROM product AS prod
LEFT JOIN producta AS prda ON prod.id = prda.id
LEFT JOIN prdoctb AS prdb ON prod.pid = prda.pid 
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    id,
    wghvalue,
    addby,prdid
   FROM prdentry
  WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY prdid
  UNION
SELECT
  id,
  wghvalue,
  addby,
  prdid
FROM
  prdentryb
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY prdid
) AS pl ON( pl.prdid = prda.prdid  )
LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname  
WHERE pl.aadby = 103 
GROUP BY pl.prdid 
ORDER BY
  pl.prdid ASC,
  pl.aadby ASC
```

in above i need  **group by pl.aadby also**

> **as per above i get below :** //

```
count | aadby  | wghval
2     | name1  | 0.3
3     | name1  | 0.6
4     | name2  | 0.2
4     | name2  | 0.3
```

> **But i need as below thats group by aadby :**

```
count | aadby  | wghval
5     | name1  | 0.9 
8     | name2  | 0.5
```

also if i remove below left join ,

> LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname
>
> THEN i don't need to do GROUP BY pl.prdid , THEN I CAN DO group by
>   pl.aadby .....but result count increase , HENCE GROUP BY pl.prdid
>   decrease my count which is giving result proper but how to do another
>   group by for aadby

Comment: WHERE pl.aadby = 103 
GROUP BY pl.aadby    use this only

Comment: when i am doing GROUP BY pl.aadby , its not showing me what i need it showing me sample data

Comment: now show us your table data

Comment: and if i remove GROUP BY pl.prdid  then i get repeat value for pl,prdid

Comment: If i keep GROUP BY pl.aadby , then i get count for name1 = 2 , but if i remove that and replace it with   GROUP BY pl.aadby , then i get  name1 = 56 , hence i need both groupby

Answer (score 0):

based on the samle data you provided .. you should use

```
 ....
WHERE pl.aadby = 103 
GROUP BY aadby
ORDER BY aadby ASC
```

Comment: when i am doing GROUP BY pl.aadby , its not showing me what i need it showing me sample data

Comment: and if i remove GROUP BY pl.prdid  then i get repeat value for pl,prdid

Comment: what do you mean with " it showing me sample data "  .. i eval your question by the sample you provide .. ....

Comment: that is not sample data ...that Output as per my query .... but i need that output as in group by aadby

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about your data and what logic you want to get your desires output. but one way I can do it as below use your query as subquery.

```
select  sum(t1.count) as count,t1.addby,sum(t1.wghvalue) wghvalue
from 
(SELECT  
  COUNT(pl.id) as count,addby,SUM(pl.wghvalue) as wghvalue
FROM product AS prod
LEFT JOIN producta AS prda ON prod.id = prda.id
LEFT JOIN prdoctb AS prdb ON prod.pid = prda.pid 
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    id,
    wghvalue,
    addby,prdid
   FROM prdentry
  WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY prdid
  UNION
SELECT
  id,
  wghvalue,
  addby,
  prdid
FROM
  prdentry
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY prdid
) AS pl ON( pl.prdid = prda.prdid  )
LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname  
WHERE pl.aadby = 103 
GROUP BY pl.prdid 
ORDER BY
  pl.prdid ASC,
  pl.aadby ASC ) t1
group by t1.addby
```

Comment: yes ..it show me result as per need ...let me test with my whole query ....thanks bhaila

Comment: hi i dont know why ...but when i remove LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname   , count remain same but wghvalue get change ....thats  with left join for name1  count = 2  and wghvalue = 45 and if i remove left join then name1  count = 2  and wghvalue = 23